# Tax situation for non-resident

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, non-resident, form-1040

I have an F1 visa and my spouse is a permanent resident with no income. My employer has deducted FICA taxes and I would like to get a refund for that as well. What will be my best options for filing? I prefer to file joint.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can file as Married Filing Jointly if you guys want. Either you are a resident alien, and so you can file jointly as both of you are resident aliens, or you are a nonresident alien and can use [Nonresident Spouse Treated as Resident](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2017_publink1000222193) to treat you as a resident alien for the whole year and then file jointly.

If you were a resident alien on F1, the FICA tax would have been deducted correctly. If you were a nonresident on F1, you should have been [exempt from FICA tax](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-student-liability-for-social-security-and-medicare-taxes) (this is true even if you used Nonresident Spouse Treated as Resident to file jointly with your spouse). You are exempt from the Substantial Presence Test for the first 5 calendar years on F1, so assuming you hadn't been to the US on F or J status before, if you came on F1 in 2012 or before, you would be a resident alien for all of 2017, but if you came on F1 in 2013 or after, you would be a nonresident alien for all of 2017. If you were a nonresident alien and they deducted FICA in error, you should first ask the employer to have it refunded. If the employer can't, [you can file](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/social-security-tax-medicare-tax-and-self-employment) Forms 843 and 8316 to IRS to ask for a refund; note that this is independent from your income tax return, and may take years to receive a response.